# Detect when the end of a combobox is scrolled to in c# windows form applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to run a function when the user scrolls to the bottom of a combobox and have been looking at the MouseWheel event but to no avail. Thanks to anyone able to help!

Comment: I don't think it is possible using WinForms alone (except maybe by using owner-draw list). And if fact, even with Win32 API it is probably not documented. So essentially, you should probably avoid it or implement your own control that behave like you want.

Comment: I guess you mean that not scroll on dropdown items, scroll on control without open dropdown. Right?

Comment: No, I mean the dropdown items